# Expecting identifier before object string :(

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to format this line correctly but so far, I'm getting no where:

```
NSString *urlAddress = selectedCell.@"html";
```

selectedCell is the category chosen,

```
IBOutlet UILabel *selectedCellText;
NSString *selectedCell;
```

How do I sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it,

```
NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:selectedCell ofType:@"htm"];
```